# Class member methods not binding to TypeScript -> JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox, binding, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have been trying to write a Firefox web extension using TypeScript. Since this is kind of a strange endeavor the extension is pretty simple; it's supposed to be a clock. I have three scripts and one class this exported as a module. My issue is that when the context changes my class-member functions don't seem to keep their bindings to their object (thereby becoming undefined). The scripts are invoked by clicking a specified page: [*click* content -> background -> content (resp)].

```
/**
 * Holds basic system/browser time data
 */
export class Clock {
  private time : string;
  private hh : number;
  private mm : number;
  private ss : number;

  constructor(date : Date) {
    this.hh = date.getHours();
    this.mm = date.getMinutes();
    this.ss = date.getSeconds();
    this.time = this.setTime();

    this.getTime = this.getTime.bind(this);
    this.logTime = this.logTime.bind(this);
  }

  public setTime = (): string => {
    return `${this.hh}:${this.mm}`;
  }

  public clockStringify = () : string => {
    const timeData = {
      hh : this.hh,
      mm : this.mm,
      ss : this.ss,
      time: this.time
    };

    return JSON.stringify(timeData);
  }

  public logTime() : void {
    console.log(`${this.hh}:${this.mm}`)
  }

  public getTime() : string {
    return this.time;
  }
}
```

```
/*
 * This is from the content.ts script which runs on top of the web-page in FF
 */
function handleResponse(clock : Clock) {
  console.log("Content RESP handler >> ");
  console.log("Clock info dump >>");
  console.log(clock.clockStringify());
  clock.logTime();
  console.log(clock.getTime());
}
```

```
/*
 * This from my background.ts script which runs in the background-page of FF
 */
function handleMessage(request : any, sender : any, sendResponse : any) {
  let clock = new Clock(new Date());

  console.log("Background handler >> " + request);
  console.log("Clock info dump >>");
  console.log(clock.clockStringify());
  clock.logTime();
  console.log(clock.getTime());

  sendResponse(clock);
}
```

The transpiled JavaScript for Clock.ts:

```
/**
 * Holds basic system/browser time data
 */
export class Clock {
    constructor(date) {
        this.setTime = () => {
            return `${this.hh}:${this.mm}`;
        };
        this.clockStringify = () => {
            const timeData = {
                hh: this.hh,
                mm: this.mm,
                ss: this.ss,
                time: this.time
            };
            return JSON.stringify(timeData);
        };
        this.hh = date.getHours();
        this.mm = date.getMinutes();
        this.ss = date.getSeconds();
        this.time = this.setTime();
        this.getTime = this.getTime.bind(this);
        this.logTime = this.logTime.bind(this);
    }
    logTime() {
        console.log(`${this.hh}:${this.mm}`);
    }
    getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

> The JavaScript for background.ts and content.ts are pretty much the same, so omitting.

I have looked all over and have arrived at the solution that can be seen above in Clock.ts. I am at a loss for what why they the bindings are not working correctly. I used different biding methods in Clock.ts to see if the is a difference, but nope.

My FF output is:

```
Webconsole context has changed
Background handler >> [object Object] background.js:6:13
Clock info dump >> background.js:7:13
{"hh":11,"mm":55,"ss":32,"time":"11:55"} background.js:8:13
11:55 Clock.js:26:17
11:55 background.js:10:13
...
Content script loaded >> content.js:1:9
Content RESP handler >> content.js:12:13
Clock info dump >> content.js:13:13
...
[extension-runners/index.js][debug] Reloading installed extensions on user request
[extension-runners/index.js][debug] Reloading all reloadable add-ons
[firefox/index.js][debug] Firefox stdout: 1586919326952 addons.xpi      WARN    Addon with ID ac86eefbc0a51ff2c5ab50e8b732e9c26c23dea6@temporary-addon already installed, older version will be disabled
[firefox/remote.js][debug] Received message from client: {"from":"root","type":"addonListChanged"}
Last extension reload: 11:55:27 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)[firefox/remote.js][debug] 

[firefox/index.js][debug] Firefox stderr: JavaScript error: moz-extension://68316183-66b2-f244-be4a-a97929269985/js/content.js, line 14: TypeError: clock.clockStringify is not a function
```

I am transpiling to `"target": "ES2016"` and `"module": "es2015"`. Is there some concept that I am missing with the bindings? Do they not work in the same context of the browser?

Comment: See the documentation for messaging: Firefox uses structured cloning so it supports only the standard JSON-compatible types and a few others like typed arrays, blobs. It can't send functions or class instances.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have looked into the docs a bit more and it seems like the cloning might be the issue, not my bindings. I have found these links:

* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts

As you stated, it seems like FF does a structured clone when sending messages and reading the docs again has lead me to realize that my architecture choice might be poor.

Comment: You mention specific documentation for messaging. I could find the WebAPI messaging (MessageEvent, MessagePort etc...) but not just "Messaging"; was there a specific one you were talking about?

Comment: I saw it in sendMessage docs. Looking at onMessage I see sendResponse is even more restrictive: it only supports JSON-compatible types, assuming the documentation is up to date though.

Comment: Looking at the `runtime.sendMessage` docs it says: 
**message: any. An object that can be structured clone serialized.**

This means that the object's are getting cloned as you stated and yes, the `sendResponse(...)` function is limited by:

**sendResponse: A function to call, at most once, to send a response to the message. The function takes a single argument, which may be any JSON-ifiable object. This argument is passed back to the message sender.**

Thanks for your help! I'll be writing up my own solution once I read up more.

Comment: Some links to the relevant docs: 
[onMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage#Sending_a_synchronous_response)
[sendMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage#Parameters)